# не обрабатывает запрос php

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Установлена связка Apace 2.4 (centos 7) + mod_php+nginx/1.12.2
Настроены виртуальные хосты. Перенесен сайт на виртуальный хост. 
Сайт работает, php файлы открываются, все хорошо,
При создании файла phpinfo.php (c директивой phpinfo для проверки) в директории сайтов 
mcedit /var/www/html/index.php

(владелец apace), 
файл не обрабатывается , то идет его сохранение, то ошибка nginx (The page you are looking for is not found.)

Comment: Ошибка в конфиге. Не скажу, пока не покажите

Comment: Какой файл конфигов нужен уточнить сможете? apache, nginx, php, virtual host или еще что?

Comment: конфиги apache + nginx

Comment: Сложно, и nginx и apache. Скачивание файла php вместо отображения - следствие того что веб сервер не знает ничего про модуль php. В конфигах значит ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, ошибка была указана в названии расширения файла виртуального хоста apache